# How to change modified date in a node when users votes more than 5 times?

Tags: rating

Mayday, mayday! :-) I have 2 views of nodes showing "published nodes" and "moderation nodes". I'm using vote_up_down in my nodes.

I want, when the users vote up a node more than 5 times, to modify the date of the node, and put it "now".

Can somebody tell me how I could do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since vote_up_down uses voting API underneath, you can use the [voting rules](https://drupal.org/project/voting_rules) module to allow you to configure rules to fire when votes are made.

You could then make a rule that fires when a vote is made, that then checks the total number of votes for that node and if it has 5 votes update the nodes updated date and save.

So the event/trigger would be voting on the node, the condition would be that the node has 5 votes (after a quick look it is likely the "Evaluate the results of a vote on a ..." condition), and the action would be updating the modified/updated date of the node.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer.
I have enabled all the modules you said (except rules conditionals, I am using Drupal 6).

My problem is, I configured correctly (I hope) my rule but then, when a user publish a new node, is not working.

Do I need anything else? Do I need to write some code?

Comment: It shouldn't really be related to publishing a new node, just when voting on a node. I have added a little more info about the rule to my answer. I have not actually tried it for this use case but it should work. You also should not need the rules conditional module. - You shouldn't need to write any code.

Comment: Hi rooby, thanks again for your answer and your time. I'll try to solve it. Best regards.

Comment: @rooby : fully agree with your recommended solution. But I also suggest you remove the last 2 phrases from it. So sad that these kinds of users always seem to forget to come back later on to provide the result of their "trying" (and maybe even mark it as accepted). Would be nice if the SE sites could come up with some type of nagging mechanism to start eMailing such users with something like "please provide feedback" ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did with the Rules Bonus Pack. There was one option to modify date information of the node.

cheers!